# Will 64 bit ubuntu work on x86-64 bit architechture?

Tags: 14.04

Will 64 bit ubuntu work on my p4 pc with x86-64 bit architechture? I'm currently using it as live usb

Answer (score 0):

yes.

If the iso runs well as a live usb, then it's working, yes?

It should install ok too, *should*

Comment: Thanx frnd your answer is very helpful

Comment: No problem, feel free to check mark / accept it. FYI, running just about any live cd/usb/dvd is almost identical to running the same system installed, and about the best way to test & make sure it'll work before actually installing.